# Raster Over Layer in Leaflet from GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, leaflet, overlay

I want to add a raster over layer onto the base layer and the raster layer is published by a Geoserver WMS. I set the raster layer's geographic coordinate system as the same as the cloudmate tiles. The raster source is a layer of the United States in the GeoServer sample data. I can get the layer in Leaflet and do spatial queries, like query a part of the raster by bounding box successfully, which means the WMS is good. But the raster image never overlays correctly. I've set the same GCS and projection. Why does that happens? Is there any successful instruction or sample about it?

Comment: maybe you could show us your code?